# How to prove implication using Proof by Cases

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Assuming that $P \land \neg Q \leftrightarrow 0$, how would we go about proving $P \leftrightarrow Q$ using proof-by-cases?

Comment: You have two different variables, $P$ and $Q$, so there are only four different cases in total. Just go through them one by one. $P$ is true (or $P=1$ in some notation) and $Q$ is false, etc...

Comment: $P \land \lnot Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot (P \to Q)$

Comment: But note that $\lnot (P \land \lnot Q) \nvDash P \leftrightarrow Q$.

Answer (score 1):

Complete the table and compare the last two columns.

$$\begin{array}{l:l} P&Q&P\wedge\neg Q& P\wedge\neg Q\leftrightarrow 0 & P\leftrightarrow Q\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 &  &  &  \\
0 & 1 &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 &  &  & \end{array}$$

Now use the results to guide you to the cases.